# What is mean Class<?>[] classes and Please give me some example

Tags: java, junit5

I don't know how to use the attributes of `@ValueSource` of JUnit 5 such as `Class<?>[]` classes.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/ValueSource.html#classes()

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(classes = { })
public void testWithValueSource3(UserInfo argument) {
    assertTrue(argument.getName().equals("Alice"));
}
```

How do I write here?

> > "classes = { }"

Comment: Please give me some example

Comment: It is a class array

Comment: Have you seen the [user guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-ValueSource)?

Comment: Yes. I saw it. But I do not know how to write the code for Classes.

Comment: I know it's a class array.
Could you give me some hints on how to write in that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-ValueSource) shows an example of using `@ValueSource` with `int` arguments.

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(ints = { 1, 2, 3 })
void testWithValueSource(int argument) {
    assertTrue(argument > 0 && argument < 4);
}
```

You'd do the same thing for the `classes` element except instead of using `int` arguments you'd use `Class<?>` arguments. Note you'd probably be able to use `Class<? extends SomeType>` as the parameter type but there's no type safety (i.e. *you* have to ensure the annotation only uses classes of that type).

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(classes = { Object.class, String.class, List.class })
void testWithValueSource(Class<?> argument) {
    // assert something...
}
```

---

However, in your question your test method accepts a `UserInfo` argument (an instance, not its class) which can't be configured using `@ValueSource`. A [`@MethodSource`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/MethodSource.html) is probably what you want to use (see [user guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource)).

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("userInfoProvider")
void testUserInfo(UserInfo argument) {
    // assert something...
}

/*
 * Doesn't necessarily have to be static or return a Stream. Read
 * the documentation to know when the method must be static and
 * what other return types are possible.
 */
static Stream<UserInfo> userInfoProvider() {
    return Stream.of(
        new UserInfo(...),
        new UserInfo(...),
        new UserInfo(...),
        // and so on...
    );
}
```